# Ui-dialog сделать над всеми элементами если у содержащего его контейнера position = fixed (не работает z-index: 101)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте! Есть `<div id="Page">`, в него вложены другие различные элементы (`<div>, <form>`), а также `<div class="ui-dialog">`. У контейнера `<div id="Page">` свойство `position: fixed`.  Когда вызывается диалоговое окно , вся страница становится затемненной и нет возможности работать с диалоговым окном. У класса "ui-dialog" указано `z-index: 101;` однако этот параметр игнорируется (не поднимается окно над всеми другими), если не убрать у контейнера `<div id="Page">` свойство `position: fixed`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Updated!  Так выглядит код:

```
// REPORT CHOOSE FORM
            $("#reportChoose-form").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true
            });
            $("#reportChoose-form").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")).css({ "z-index": "101" });
```

Вот так выглядит структура страницы (упрощенно):

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header" style="text-align: center"></div>            
        <div id="mainMenu"></div>
        <div id="body">
            <div class="inner">
                <div id="mainMessageBox"></div>
                <div id="data">@RenderSection("bodySection")</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @RenderSection("scriptsSection")        
    </div>
</body>
```

Модальное окно находится в `<div id="data">@RenderSection("bodySection")</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй блок `<div class="ui-dialog">` вынести за пределы `<div id="Page">` и позиционировать относительно body.

Comment: Добавила код структуры страницы. Не уверенна, что модальное окно (их несколько разных) можно вынести за пределы Page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ - если есть возможность, залей сюда(в общих чертах)

Comment: Идея оказалась верной: если "ui-dialog" оказывается за пределами "Page", то все работает (добилась этого, убрав строчку $("#reportChoose-form").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first")).css({ "z-index": "101" });). Однако, в моем случае решение не поможет, т.к. модальные окна содержат submit и если их вынести за пределы Page, не вызывается метод контролера.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то посмотрите, есть ли у ui-dialog свойство position: relative. Если нету - то пропишите, и z-index должен заработать.

Comment: Не помогло, по-прежнему даилоговое окно не активно

Comment: Жаль. Тогда хотелось бы больше информации для решения проблемы. 
На вскидку, попробуйте задать для .ui-dialog ещё больше z-index.

Comment: Пробовала, результата нет